# Outer measure of set of points where a given function is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reviewing for a measure theory midterm and I'm having difficulty with the following problem. I don't need it fully solved, maybe just a few hints, I'm having trouble getting started.

Let $f: \mathbf{R}\to [0,\infty]$ be defined by $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(x-b_n)^2}$ where $a_i\in(0,\infty)$ with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^{1/3} < \infty$ and $(b_n)$ is any sequence in $\mathbf{R}$.

Show that the Lebesgue outer measure of the set $\{x\in \mathbf{R} : f(x)=\infty\}$ is zero.

Comment: I cannot solve it, but I would try developing the following idea. We know that a function $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is such that $\{x:g(x)=+\infty\}$ is a null set. This is not the case of our function $f$, because it has some big non-integrable poles at $\{b_n\ :\ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. However, if you fix an $\epsilon>0$ and consider the set $$X=\mathbb{R}\setminus \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (b_n-\epsilon, b_n+\epsilon), $$ then using the monotone convergence theorem you can prove that $f\in L^1(X)$. This should be a starting point, I hope.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro That seems like it may work--I don't see how the reason for having $\sum_n a_n^{1/3}<\infty$ specifically though. Do you have any thoughts?